# How to redirect a ListView to DetailView if queryset is a single object?

Tags: django

I have a ListView with a custom get_queryset() method and a DetailView, but I would like to avoid showing the ListView when the queryset returns only one object (I want to redirect the user to the DetailView of that object).

Is there a way to accomplish that using class based views? I tried with a redirect inside the get_queryset() of ListView, but it doesn't work and I can't find anything useful in the ListView class documentation.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of a restful API. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a form where the user can search for objects by their name or part of it. If the user searches for part of the name and more than one result is returned I want to show them the ListView, but if the user searches for the exact name, I want to redirect them directly to the DetailView of the object.

Comment: I think the client side logic should handle using the list view or the detail view. The server shouldn't know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified Ivan's answer a bit (the use of `count()` method was wrong and I also need to use slug instead of pk for my DetailView), so the solution was:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyListView(ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset() 
        if len(queryset) == 1:
            return redirect('your_detail_view_url', queryset.first().pk)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Note. To get status 301, use redirect("somewhere", permanent=True)

Answer (score 3):

You must call `redirect` inside `get`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyListView(ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset() 
        if queryset.count() == 1:
            return redirect('your_detail_view_url', pk=queryset.first().pk)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was searching for, but I had to modify it a bit: the `queryset.count()` requires one mandatory parameter, the object I want to count for in the list, so I used `len(queryset)`.

Comment: Note. To get status 301, use redirect("somewhere", permanent=True)